# Lines connecting at vertices not included in ArcGIS Pro Network Analyst service area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, topology

**Situation:** I'm attempting to generate drivetime areas for a pedestrian walking network using Network Analyst in ArcGIS Pro 2.9. The walking network feature dataset has many lines from one feature class joined at vertices as well as endpoints. Before I build the network, I'm using the network dataset "endpoint" group connectivity policy.

**Problem:** When I generate the service area, I notice that lines that were snapped to vertices rather than endpoints are not included in the area. However, I can't change the connectivity rule to "any vertex," because there are bridges and overpasses in my network that aren't supposed to connect with the lines they pass over.

[image]

(Circled in red is one such example of a line that was snapped to a vertex or edge rather than an endpoint, and is not included in the service area.)

Should I find all lines that snap to vertices/edges rather than endpoints and split at those vertices? If so, how would I find those lines? Are there better solutions to this problem? I have not found a topology rule that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the approach that worked for me was to allow the initial network to connect anywhere segments intersected and then I used these network nodes to split all segments in the source dataset using Split Line at Point. Then I rebuilt the network only allowing connection at endpoints and tested. I then removed nodes at locations like bridges by dissolving those segments into a single segment again.